# How can I upload my ios app to apple store?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My iOS app is based on WebView.
I want to register this app to app store.
After submit, I can see this message from support team.

> Hello,Thank you for your patience.
>
> Regarding 4.2.0, your app provides a limited user experience as it is not sufficiently different from a mobile website. Specifically, your app does not contain any native iOS features within the app.
>
> To resolve this issue, it would be appropriate to revise your app to provide a more robust user experience by including additional native iOS functionality..
>
> We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app."

How can I upload my app to app store?
My app is just to show only website on iOS webview. Just a simple app.

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**.

I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but unless you change your app to significantly use some native iOS features, Apple will continue to decline your app. This is to ensure a minimum level of quality in the apps available. Due to this regulation, WebView-centric apps will not be accepted on the store. Please have a read on the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) to help you understand

If you really want to get it up on the store, you will have to add features. Otherwise, there are alternative distribution solutions that don't require publishing to the App store, but more often than not they are for businesses & in-house deployment.

Comment: I really want to upload this app to app store .
What should I do for this ?
Please tell me in detail.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wrote. You *can't* and *won't* ever be able to publish a WebView-only app. In the eyes of Apple, if you have to do that kind of app, it's that your user could be using your website anyways.

Comment: Your only alternative is to build an actual app, replicating the features you want from your website. WebViews are to be used only sparingly, in some situations where iOS wouldn't be enough, or where there is specific & justifiable business needs.

Comment: So , possibility rate is just 0% ?  with only webviews,

Comment: As I explained twice already, yes. It is impossible to publish a webview-only app on the app store. Read the guidelines I linked.

Comment: Please check these carefully.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/emx/id1472856202?ls=1

https://emxmart.com/

This is also web-app, but this is approved in app store.
How can I think of this problem ?
Sorry, Ferdz

Comment: I don't understand why you're debating this with me, I'm simply explaining Apple's rules to you. That app seems to have a WhatsApp integration, and might take advantage of other native features, which might've been enough for Apple to justify it's existence on the App Store.

Comment: That app is certainly NOT *just* a webview, or else it would've been denied.

Comment: You have to ask "What can I do in the app that I couldn't do with a web site?"  - Paulw11

Comment: one more question:
To approve my app , what function can I add to existing website ?
Do you have any smart method for that ?

Comment: You are right , just my sent apps have some native features like firebase push notifications.